# The package 'pin_code_fields' isn't a dependency of the importing package. Try adding a dependency for 'pin_code_fields' in the 'pubspec.yaml' file

Tags: flutter

Does anyone have a solution for this?

[flutter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT0VJ.png)

I typed all the following commands in the terminal but nothing.

"flutter package get "

"flutter packages upgrade"

"flutter pub get"

"flutter pub add flutter_pin_code_fields".
I added "
flutter_pin_code_fields: ^2.2.0
I added "flutter_pin_code_fields: ^2.2.0" to the dependencies in File < pubspec.yaml > , saved and restarted the IDE, which is VScode.

Comment: Add your package in your Pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Share your pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

If you add a package by this command

```
flutter pub add flutter_pin_code_fields
```

then you don't need to do this manually in your file `pubspec.yaml` like this

```
dependencies:
  flutter_pin_code_fields: ^2.2.0
```

After running a command or adding manually in `pubspec.yaml`, do this:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

### In "pubspec.yaml": (manually)

- ✔ You have to add the package to

```
dependencies:
  package_name: vesion
```

- ✖ And not to

```
dev_dependencies: 
  package_name: version
```

### In terminal:

- you can add packages to `dependencies` through this command:

```
flutter pub add package_name
```

- then, refreshing dependencies if needed:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```